# Unresponsive when network is on, ok if off

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-note

Since a few weeks, my phone is behaving strangely, it works OK in airplane mode but when the network is on i get several of the following symptoms:

- the phone becomes partially unresponsive, i experience freezes, lags
- apps like twitter often crash and are very slow
- the phone reboots by itself
- the battery usage becomes very high (emptying a fully charged phone within the hour)
- the phone overheats

I have also noticed that when networking is on the battery charging indicator is stopping and starting alternatively (like 1-2 secs work, 1-2 secs frozen). This does not happen when airplane mode is on (indicator progress is fluid).

How do i troubleshoot this problem? Are there some diag tools i could use or logs i could check?

What i have tried so far:

- install all app updates (but i have trouble doing that as google play works erraticaly)
- reset cache & davik partitions from the cm menu
- clear the cache of twitter & google play
- delete google play history

My combo:

- Galaxy Note 1 - N7000
- CyanogenMod 11-20160815-NIGHTLY-n7000
- Android 4.4.4
- Band version: N7000XXLT3

EDIT: This is not linked to a ROM update (last ROM update was 9 months ago and the trouble started about 1 month ago).

Comment: Well you are using a Note 1, which is beyond old in technology years.  And you are also using a custom ROM.  These 2 things combined can cause problems.  What does using the factory ROM do?

Comment: @bmdixon please check edit

Comment: @sixandseven8ths thanks but your suggestion sounds a little bit too much like "ah you have a problem with windows, did you try to reinstall it?"

Comment: It's more like "you replaced Windows with a homebrew version that even the author thinks doesn't work, and now you want us to debug it for you?"